# heartbeat timeout error in tsunami deamon

Tags: scp, udp

I am trying to transfer a large file from server A to server B using tsunami.

I am getting following error:

```
Heartbeat timeout of 15 seconds reached, terminating transfer.
```

And here are details:

Receiving server:

```
tsunami> get master_bkup.csv.gz
Receiving data on UDP port 46224
             last_interval                   transfer_total                   buffers      transfer_remaining  OS UDP
time          blk    data       rate rexmit     blk    data       rate rexmit queue  ring     blk   rt_len      err
00:00:00.625   50   0.00M    0.6Mbps   1.9%      50    0.0G    0.6Mbps   0.0%     1     0 14140749        1        0 --
```

---

Sending Server:

```
   n/a     n/a     n/a  285839   2.02   1 -- no heartbeat since 12.74s
100000 83.24us    12us  294039   2.08   1
   n/a     n/a     n/a  294039   2.08   1 -- no heartbeat since 13.39s
100000 86.71us    12us  300189   2.12   1
   n/a     n/a     n/a  300189   2.12   1 -- no heartbeat since 13.91s
100000 90.32us    12us  306339   2.17   1
   n/a     n/a     n/a  306339   2.17   1 -- no heartbeat since 14.44s
100000 94.09us    12us  312489   2.21   1
   n/a     n/a     n/a  312489   2.21   1 -- no heartbeat since 14.99s
100000 98.01us    12us  318639   2.25   1
   n/a     n/a     n/a  318639   2.25   1 -- no heartbeat since 15.57s
Heartbeat timeout of 15 seconds reached, terminating transfer.
Server 1 transferred 14480178012 bytes in 16.20 seconds (6820.4 Mbps)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line on receiving server and now the transfer is possible

```
set rate 509600
```